# IdentityServer3 returns user profile information without user's consent

Tags: identityserver3

I am using identityserver3 for authentication using OpenIDConnect.  I noticed IdentityServer3 is returning user’s profile information even if user has not given consent. I'm not sure if this default behavior or it’s a bug. Its happening when I configured clients, scope and users using EF and AspNetIdentity. 
This is how I configured the IdentityServer

**User**

```
Properties
    UserName: Someusername
    Password: SomePassword
    Email: user@domain.com
    Phone:1234567
Claims:
   Country: US
   TimeZoneID: CST
```

**Scope (openid)**

```
Name: openid
Enabled: true
Type: 0 ( ie. Identity)
```

**Client**

```
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifeTime: 300
AccessTokenLifeTime: 7200
ClientID: LocalHostMvcClient
Client Name: Local Host Client
Enabled: true
EnableLocalLoging: true
IdentityTokenLifetimne:300
PrefixClientClaims: true
RequireConsent:true
AllowAccessTokenViaBrowser:true
Scopes: openid
```

Note that there is no `profile` scope has been added, that means client cannot request profile information and so does user cannot consent profile information. User can only consent identity information.

[image: Here is SQL Storage]

I have configured the client as below

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44314/identity",
            Scope = "openid",
            ClientId = "LocalHostMvcClient",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:34937/",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications

                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                        {
                            var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);

                            // get userinfo data
                            var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                                new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                                n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                            var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                            userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));                                

                            n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                                nid,
                                n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        }
                }
        });
    }
```

I was expecting `userInfoClient.GetAsync()` will only return `preferred_username` and `sub` claims. However its returning all user’s profile information as well. Like phonenumber, email, Country and TimeZoneID.
I have noticed this behavior happening only if i configured users,scopes and clients in SQL using EF & AspNetIdentity. I don’t see this happening if I configured in memory

**Update1** *(Issue as per Brock Allen's Reply Below)*

```
    public class UserService : AspNetIdentityUserService<User, string>
    {
        public UserService(UserManager userMgr)
            : base(userMgr)
        {
        }
    }



    public class AspNetIdentityUserService<TUser, TKey> : UserServiceBase
        where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>, new()
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        ..
        ..
        ..
        ..
        public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext ctx)
        {
            var subject = ctx.Subject;
            var requestedClaimTypes = ctx.RequestedClaimTypes;

            if (subject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("subject");

            TKey key = ConvertSubjectToKey(subject.GetSubjectId());
            var acct = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(key);
            if (acct == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subject identifier");
            }

            var claims = await GetClaimsFromAccount(acct);
            if (requestedClaimTypes != null && requestedClaimTypes.Any())
            {
                claims = claims.Where(x => requestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
            }

            ctx.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }   
    }
```

**Update2**
The following fix seems to be working for me.

```
    public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext ctx)
    {
        var requestedClaimTypes = ctx.RequestedClaimTypes;
        if (requestedClaimTypes != null && requestedClaimTypes.Any())
        {
            var subject = ctx.Subject;

            if (subject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("subject");

            TKey key = ConvertSubjectToKey(subject.GetSubjectId());
            var acct = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(key);
            if (acct == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subject identifier");
            }

            var claims = await GetClaimsFromAccount(acct);
            claims = claims.Where(x => requestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
            ctx.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }
    }
```

However, I also have noticed one more issue. On `profile` scope even if i set `IncludeAllCliamsForUser` to `true` , still in `GetProfileDataAsync` method `ctx.RequestedClaimTypes` returns null.
So UserInfo endpoint does not return any claims even if client is requesting `profile`

To get this working, in addition to above fix, I also have to explicitly add user claims to `profile` scope and set `IncludeAllCliamsForUser` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

If your user service implementation's `GetProfileData` is not honoring the `RequestedClaimTypes` context parameter then this is the source of the leak. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: `https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/userinfo.html` The documentation for UserInfo endpoint says "The UserInfo endpoint can be used to retrieve identity information about a subject. It requires a valid access token with at least the ‘openid’ scope".

Comment: Please see update1 above, that's the current implementation. Looks like if `requestedClaimTypes` is null then its returning all the Claims..